# How to extract month in measure when calculating cumulative total

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I can calculate cumulative using dates

```
Cumul Open Claims = 
 CALCULATE([Open Claims],
    FILTER(
        ALL(fact_Losses[DateOpened]),
        (fact_Losses[DateOpened]) <= MAX(fact_Losses[DateOpened])
    )
```

But how can I simply do the same but monthly cumulative. 
Basically what would be the syntax to extract month from date in this measure.

Something like this, but it gives me syntax error

```
Cumul Open Claims = 
 CALCULATE([Open Claims],
    FILTER(
        ALL(MONTH(fact_Losses[DateOpened])),
        MONTH(fact_Losses[DateOpened]) <= MAX(MONTH(fact_Losses[DateOpened]))
    )
```

Comment: Don't think you can have the MONTH function inside the ALL function. You have to write ALL(fact_Losses[DateOpened]) 
however in your code you will get (if run today in March) Jan-March of all years in the fact_Losses table. If this table only includes one year you safe. If not then add an additional YEAR(date) = Year(Today()) filter argument to limit the calculation to this year
Cheers, Oscar

Answer (score 0):

All I have to do is simply reference table name in `ALL` function, not column name.

```
Cumul Open Claims = 
CALCULATE( [Open Claims],
FILTER(
    ALL(fact_Losses),
    fact_Losses[DateOpened] <= MAX(fact_Losses[DateOpened]) 
)
)
```